# Displaying GPS Direction on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have all the data including latitude,longitude and gps direction, How to draw vehicle with going direction
I can draw the vehicle on the map, using this

```
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vehicle_move_green);
        MapVehicles objMapVehicles=new MapVehicles(drawable, this);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","");

        objMapVehicles.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(objMapVehicles);
        mapController.setCenter(point);
        mapController.setZoom(17);
```

I need this picture should show the moving direction, as i have GPS direction number

Answer (score 0):

you want to draw the direction from your current place, just go through [here](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-%E2%80%93-part-2-draw-the-route/)